# Git on the server(windows server 2012)

Tags: git, gitlab, windows-server-2012

We want to install `Git` in our dedicated server to mange our code version and code revision. Our dedicated server has Windows server 2012. We thought about `GitLab`, but it is not supported in windows. Suggest me which one should I use, there is `Gitprep` for windows.

Answer (score 22):

You could use [Bonobo Git Server](http://bonobogitserver.com/), it is designed to run on Windows in IIS.

Answer (score 6):

It would be best, on Windows, to host a virtual image (as in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) of a Unix server, in which you can benefit from all the git repo hosting services, like GitLab)

If not, [**Gitblit**](http://gitblit.com/) is a good (and portable, available on Windows) alternative.

Comment: wont that create performance overhead?

Comment: @Smrita no, the "performance" of such a server doesn't have to be outstanding to work well, and the overhead of a virtualized server is nowadays quite small. If you want even a smaller one, use a Docker image through boot2docker: https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/. Then the overhead is *really* small.

Answer (score 6):

You can try Git Candy, A Git platform based on ASP.NET MVC. Now, GitCandy supported to SSH protocol.

Source on http://github.com/Aimeast/GitCandy

Demo on http://gitcandy.com/